# Problems with gcc 7 and 8 (debian) in OpenMP offloading to nvptx

Tags: c, gcc, openmp, offloading

I installed both [`gcc-7`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gcc-7), [`gcc-8`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gcc-8), [`gcc-7-offload-nvptx`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gcc-7-offload-nvptx) and [`gcc-8-offload-nvptx`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/gcc-8-offload-nvptx)

I tried with both to compile a simple OpenMP code with offloading:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    #pragma omp target
    #pragma omp teams distribute parallel for
    for (int i=0; i<omp_get_num_threads(); i++)
        printf("%d in %d of %d\n",i,omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
}
```

With the following line (with `gcc-7` too):

```
gcc-8 code.c -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none
```

But it doesn't compile, giving the following error:

```
/tmp/ccKESWcF.o: In function "main":
teste.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to "GOMP_target_ext"
/tmp/cc0iOH1Y.target.o: In function "init":
ccPXyu6Y.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to "GOMP_offload_register_ver"
/tmp/cc0iOH1Y.target.o: In function "fini":
ccPXyu6Y.c:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to "GOMP_offload_unregister_ver"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

some clues?

Comment: The code compiles fine in a clang distribution that I have

Comment: It seems that libgomp.so is too old.

Comment: You code compiles and runs on the CPU but fails on the GPU for me. Are you sure your Clang solution is actually running on the GPU? I suspect it's actually running on the CPU.  Have you looked at `sudo nvprof ./a.out` (assuming Nvidia) is actually being used?

Comment: Yes, I looked. 1024 threads are generated and executed from gpu, according to nvprof. nvprof results: https://pastebin.com/05Nv3m7v

Comment: @648trindade I don't understand how `printf` would work on the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You code compiles and runs for me using `-foffload=disable -fno-stack-protector` with `gcc7` and `gcc-7-offload-nvptx` and Ubuntu 17.10.

But on the GPU (without `-foffload=disable`) it fails to compile. You can't call `printf` from the GPU.  Instead you can do this:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int nthreads;
  #pragma omp target teams map(tofrom:nthreads)
  #pragma omp parallel
  #pragma omp single
  nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();

  int *ithreads = malloc(sizeof *ithreads *nthreads);

  #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for map(tofrom:ithreads[0:nthreads])
  for (int i=0; i<nthreads; i++) ithreads[i] = omp_get_thread_num();

  for (int i=0; i<nthreads; i++)
    printf("%d in %d of %d\n", i, ithreads[i], nthreads);

  free(ithreads);  
}
```

For me this outputs

```
0 in 0 of 8
1 in 0 of 8
2 in 0 of 8
3 in 0 of 8
4 in 0 of 8
5 in 0 of 8
6 in 0 of 8
7 in 0 of 8
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile too on gcc-7 or gcc-8. But compiles on clang :/

Comment: However, if I set `-foffload=disable` I got the following error https://pastebin.com/aSV8eSa5

So, I suspected that my libgomp is outdated, like @ilya-verbin said. But `dpkg -l | grep libgomp` shows this version https://pastebin.com/5WRzJcMS

Comment: Please check that `ldd a.out` points to libgomp.so version 8 (or 7 when you use gcc-7).

Comment: @648trindade, OpenMP reports 8 threadds in the target region on the GPU. I know that sounds strange. The CPU also reports 8 threads. `simd` makes a big difference on the GPU so I suspect the threads in OpenMP target regions are not SIMT threads  but more like a warp. I have a GTX 1060. It has 20 SM units each which have 4 "cores" and each of those area warp so 32 SIMT threads -> 20*4*32 max. OpenMP defaults to 30 teams of 8 threads on my system.

Comment: @Zboson I'm testing on a Titan X GPU, and clang implementation returns 992 threads with `omp_get_num_threads` inside a target and parallel region. If I call `omp_get_num_threads` inside of parallel for, and set `teams distribute`directive, the number of threads returned is 1024

Comment: @IlyaVerbin I cannot run `ldd` because `gcc` doesn't even compile the code. `clang` implementation links `libomp.so.5` (from `libomp5`package) and the compiled `libomptarget.so`

Comment: And what is in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: @IlyaVerbin Actually there was the clang's `lib` dir on `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (－‸ლ). I removed and all worked fine. Sorry for my dumbness. I should remove the question?

Comment: @Zboson now gcc reports 8 threads for me too. Titan X has 28 SM units, 128 "cores" per SM, reporting 3584 cuda cores.

Comment: gcc apparently has an upper bound of 72 teams (if I set more, omp defaults to 72) and `omp_get_max_threads` returns 8 inside a target region

Comment: @648trindade, I think it might be a bug in `omp_get_num_threads`. It's possibly not ready for `target`.  In terms of speed for the few tests I have done OMP on the GPU is competitive with OpenACC so the bug is asking the number of threads.